# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: java, spring

hi i am getting the following exception while running my application
and my applicationContext.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/SureshDB"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/jsfcompref/register/UserTa.hbm.xml</value></list>
        </property></bean>
    <bean id="UserTaDAO" class="com.jsfcompref.register.UserTaDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="UserTaService" class="com.jsfcompref.register.UserTaServiceImpl">
        <property name="userTaDao">
            <ref bean="UserTaDAO"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

> Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

any suggestion would be heplful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exception

> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit

Hibernate depends on asm

Go to Spring installation directory and **include all of jars** in the following folders

```
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/asm/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/dom4j/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/antlr/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/jakarta-commons/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/javassist
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/cglib/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/hibernate // without hibernate-entitymanager.jar
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/slf4j/
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/j2ee/persistence.jar
<SPRING_HOME>/lib/j2ee/jta.jar
```

I hope now it runs ok

Do not forget include MySQL driver if you do not want to see a new exception